# Mouse occasionally get stuck in linux

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, kubuntu

Mouse occasionally get stuck in linux. this is not only with a particular software.i tried different wireless mouses (dell and lenovo) with dongles.
it does not show this behaviour in mac and windows.

i have tried out kubuntu ,ubuntu and debian all showing the same problem.

`hwinfo --mouse` gives me the output

```
28: USB 00.0: 10503 USB Mouse                                   
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: YccR.r8_Z6uF5n00
  Parent ID: uIhY.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 3-9:1.0
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "Lenovo Wireless Mouse"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x17ef "Lenovo"
  Device: usb 0x60d1 "Lenovo Wireless Mouse"
  Revision: "1.00"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0045
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse0)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse0, /dev/input/event5, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Lenovo_Lenovo_Wireless_Mouse-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:9:1.0-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Lenovo_Lenovo_Wireless_Mouse-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:9:1.0-mouse
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:32)
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v17EFp60D1d0100dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 5
    Wheels: 4
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #23 (Hub)
```

and `xinput list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lenovo Lenovo Wireless Mouse              id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lenovo Lenovo Wireless Mouse Consumer Control id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard System Control      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo Lenovo Wireless Mouse System Control   id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo Lenovo Wireless Mouse Consumer Control id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

please help!
:)

Comment: Why did you remove the list of devices? As it stands now this problem is "impossible" to solve because it requires diagnosing / troubleshooting or guessing what the cause might be. This problem is not a good fit for stackexchange Q / A format. You can edit your question to improve the chances of getting a response. Learn more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: solved the problem using A simple usb extender .how idk .all my native usb ports are working fine also but when i plugged the dongle to a usb extender it seem to work and there is no sign of the mouse problem till now .

thank you